# How do you derive the formula for the derivative when C is known and when it is not?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the formula for the slope of the tangent line when c is known is[image: formula] and that the slope of the secant line is [image: formula] but I don't really understand how. When c is not known, I don't understand what h is and how that formula is derived:[image: formula]

Comment: Observe that $x-c \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow c$. This suggests that the value $x-c$ is a great candidate for $h$.

Comment: $c$ is the point at which the derivative is being taken. In the form you say you understand we are taking the derivative at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a point $c$, as you've noted the slope of the tangent line to $f$ at point $c$ is given by: $$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c} {f(x) -f(c) \over x -c}$$

We can introduce a new variable, $h$, that's dependant on $x$ through:
$$h = x-c$$
Notice that we can rewrite $x$ in terms of $h$ by:
$$x = h + c$$
Thus allowing us to change our dependence on $x$ to a dependence on $h$, which allows us to rewrite our first known as:
$$f'(c)= \lim_{h+c\to c} {f(h+c) -f(c) \over h+c-c}$$
Notice that when $h+c\to c$, that is the sum $h+c$ approaches $c$, you have $h\to0$, that is $h$ approaches $0$, and vice-versa. Thus allowing us to rewrite this again as:
$$f'(c) = \lim_{h\to 0} {f(c+h) - f(c) \over h}$$
This formula is independent of $c$! and so, you can put anything regardless if it has known value or not, and so by simply changing the $c$ to be an $x$ to aid visualization that the choice of the point where you calculate the slope is arbitrary you get:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h) - f(x) \over h}$$

This is how you'd derive this formula, I'll be sure to update / reply in a comment if need be.